# Strange IC input leakage current

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, input, leakage-current

I am reading the datasheet of the [HEF4894BT](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1100000-1199999/001116132-da-01-en-IC_REGISTER_SH_HEF4894BT_112_SOIC_20_NXP.pdf).
First I saw the input clamping current is rated at 10mA and than I saw the input leakage current would be 10mA, too.
I thought the input clamping current is the current at which the IC is getting damaged and the input leakage current is the current which normally flows if I apply 5V or 0V to the input pin.
**So 10mA input leakage current is wrong (Typing error)?**
I am also wondering about the big amount of the leakage current.
On other datasheets its normally much smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further down the datasheet the Input Leakage current is specified again:
[image]
Those figures are the maximum Input leakage currents at -40, 25, 85 and 125 degree C, and when Vin is equal to either Vss or Vdd. Use either 0.1uA or 1uA depending on the environmental conditions which your product will be subjected.

Specifying an input leakage current of 10mA is confusing and not very useful. The only time you will see that is when the Vin is greater than Vdd, but that is covered by the Input clamping current parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is the limiting values and not typical values. Read the rest of the data sheet for typical values.

Comment: But I have also pay attention to the worst case. I am driving the IC from a microcontroller and the output pins of it are limited to 2mA. So I am not sure wheteher its dangerous to connect the IC serial inputs directly to it?

Comment: As long as the micro and this IC use the same supply voltage (Vcc) you do not have to worry about this. Also 2 mA is the maximum output current ot the micro, it does not mean that 2 mA will actually flow. It will not if you just connect the micro's outputs to the HEF4894's inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that these are the **Limiting values**, meaning: do not exceed or you'll break the chip ! So I think for both input clamping current and leakage current the value is correct at 10 mA.

Note how the input leakage current is a **maximum** value, this says **nothing** about the typical leakage current. Only that it should not exceed 10 mA. Which corresponds with the input clamping current which is determined by the maximum (continous DC) current the ESD diodes can handle.